# How can I read a text file, count duplications in its sequence, and rewrite it without duplications

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm currently developing an experimental image compression program; right now I am able to make this program take the RGB values from an image file and print them into a text file. The problem that I am having is that the file is WAY too big (obviously) and I'm wanting to shrink it down.

Here's an example of the output values:

```
9 14 10
9 14 10
9 14 10
9 14 10
10 12 9
10 12 9
10 12 9
10 12 9
10 12 9
12 17 13
9 14 10
8 13 9
7 12 8
6 11 7
...
```

You can already tell that this can add up in file size the larger the image is.

I'm trying to find a way for my program to write the output to a text file (which it does) located in a temp files folder, read the text file, see if any line it reads is the exact same as the next line and if so, I want it to count how many times it occurs within that sequence while leaving only one of the duplicates, and write the new output to a new text file while deleting the initial text file within the folder (Eventually I will create a custom file extension for the final compressed file that the program will read).

In short, this is the result I am trying to go for:

```
9 14 10 x4
10 12 9 x5
12 17 13
9 14 10
8 13 9
7 12 8
6 11 7
...
```

I've taken a lot of time trying to find a method of achieving this task. The only results that I have found were code snippets that can count the lines of a text file and display how many times a line is repeated throughout the **ENTIRE** file. This is **NOT** the way I want this program to work. It will result in a major error in decompression.

Any assistance or improvements is much appreciated, and please ***DO NOT COPY MY IDEA!!!***

Comment: It also appears you are very new to asking questions on StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help], take the [tour] and especially read [ask], for information on the purpose of this site and guidelines for asking questions.

Comment: So you've created a bitmap file format. In plain text. And you want help making a compression algorithm for it. Neat.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I am new at this, I'll look at that now. I'm just wanting to finish this project; it's been biting me in the butt for a while now XD. Thanks

Comment: shouldn't the first line of the output be 9 14 10 x4 ?

Comment: @user641887 Oops, I did not see that, thank you for saying that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, i gave it my first pass and it looks like to be working.

below is the code and the test cases which i tried.

HTH..

Code:

```
package tes;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ImageCompression {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ImageCompression compression = new ImageCompression();
        compression.readandwriteFile();
    }

    public void readandwriteFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

        String inputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\yc03ak1\\Desktop\\A.txt";
        String outputFilePath = "C:\\Users\\yc03ak1\\Desktop\\B.txt";

        File inputFile = new File(inputFilePath);
        File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath);

        if (!inputFile.exists() || !outputFile.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("file not found");
        }

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
        try {
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        String line = "";
        String previousLine = "";
        int counter = 0;
        int i =0; 
        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (i==0) {

                        previousLine = line;
                        counter++;
                        i++;
                        continue;

                }


                if (previousLine.equals(line)) {
                     counter++;
                }else {

                    if (counter>1) {
                        bufferedWriter.write(previousLine +" x"+counter);
                    }else {
                        bufferedWriter.write(previousLine);
                    }
                    bufferedWriter.newLine();
                    counter=1;
                }
                previousLine = line;


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (bufferedWriter != null) {

                try {
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   

    }




    }

}
```

Input A.txt

> ```
> 9 14 10
> 9 14 10
> 9 14 10
> 9 14 10
> 10 12 9
> 10 12 9
> 10 12 9
> 10 12 9
> 10 12 9
> 12 17 13
> 9 14 10
> 8 13 9
> 7 12 8
> 6 11 7
> ```

output:

B.txt

```
 9 14 10 x4
10 12 9 x5
12 17 13
9 14 10
8 13 9
7 12 8
```

HTH in your experimental image compression program.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, now I can proceed with the rest of my coding!

Comment: Can u please upvote the answer if u feel it's correct and mark it complete